# .netcore3 / EF / HostedService: Data gets deleted only on second run

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I am running a hosted service every minute. The service stores data in a table from a cache, afterwards it uses the data and sends a mail. Then it deletes the record. I have to do that, because if sending mail fails, I can retry it with the same record.

So the service takes the data from cache. Stores it in the table.
It takes the data from table and sends the mail. 
On success it deletes the record from the table.
But, a minute later, the mails got send a second time.
It seams so, that the record does not get deleted the first time.

I am doing something like this (shortend code):

```
// my hostedservice class
public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
     // start timer
     _timer = new Timer(DoWork, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_timeout));
     return Task.CompletedTask;
}

private void DoWork(object state)
{
     using var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
     ICacheService cacheService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ICacheService>();
     IMailService mailService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IMailService>();
     // transfer mails from cache
     for(...) {
          mailRepo.CreateMail(tmpMails[i]).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
          // cache gets cleared successfully, transfer is done only one time
     }
     // send mails
     List<Mail> mails = mailRepo.GetMailsForSend().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
     for(...) {
          // send mail
          // this one seems to work only on second time
          mailRepo.DeleteMail(mail).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
     }
}
// mailRepo
public async Task<bool> CreateMail(Mail mail)
{
     Add(mail);
     await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
     return true;
}
public async Task<bool> DeleteMail(Mail mail)
{
     Delete(mail);
     await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
     return true;
}
public async Task<List<Mail>> GetMailsForSend()
{
     return await _context.Set<Mail>().Where(m => m.NextTry<=DateTime.Now).ToListAsync();
}
// base functions, just for completion
public virtual void Add(T entity)
        {
            EntityEntry dbEntityEntry = _context.Entry<T>(entity);
            _context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
        }
public virtual void Delete(T entity)
        {
            EntityEntry dbEntityEntry = _context.Entry<T>(entity);
            dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Deleted;
        }
```

Please give me a hint, how i can improve my code, or what the cause could be.

**Update 02.06.2020**

I found out that everything works like expected when using separated scopes.

```
private void DoWork(object state)
{
     using(var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope()) {
        ICacheService cacheService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ICacheService>();
        IMailService mailService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IMailService>();
        // transfer mails from cache
        for(...) {
            mailRepo.CreateMail(tmpMails[i]).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            // cache gets cleared successfully, transfer is done only one time
        }
     }
     using(var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope()) {
        IMailService mailService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IMailService>();
         // send mails
         List<Mail> mails = mailRepo.GetMailsForSend().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
         for(...) {
              // send mail
              // gets deleted on first run now
              mailRepo.DeleteMail(mail).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
         }
    }
}
```

Is creating and directly deleting data in the same scope maybe the problem?

Thanks!